# Не стартует убунту 10.10 после апдейта

Tags: ubuntu

Короче говоря - давно не заходил в неё, тут решил ламп поставить, как-то мне удобней просто с этим работать, нежели на винде. Загрузился, отнекался от обновлений, поработал немного. Потом решил обновиться. Обновил, рестартнул машину, грузится убунту, потом выдается эррорка красным шрифтом на виртуалбокс, дальше розовый экран убунтовский, потом сразу тёмный, и всё. При переходе в темный, слышно, что вентиляторы успокаиваются. Ctrl+Alt+F1 ничего не дает.

p.s. live cd нету.p.p.s. какую инфу надо ещё, чтобы разобраться?

Comment: перезагрузи

Comment: Очень смешно, да.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Ubuntu нет простого способа откатить обновления, поэтому есть смысл сделать так:

1. Во время загрузки выбрать предыдущее ядро.
2. Во время загрузки выбрать Recovery Mode (Esc или левый Shift).
3. После загрузки просмотреть [системные логи](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LinuxLogFiles).
4. Удалить то, что дает ошибку или на чем зависает (если возможно).

Comment: В Recovery mode получилось загрузиться. На какие логи смотреть по таким симптомам? Смотрел Xorg, но там кроме пары ворнингов ничего не было, и то, ворнинги вроде безобидные - один на flgrx систему переключал (да, да, у меня АТИшка, к сожалению), другой не помню, но кажется не существенный.p.s. виртуалбокс удалил, но ошибка на чето другое вываливается при загрузке, не успеваю прочитать.

Answer (score 0):

Обновил драйвер на видео, всё нормально стартануло. Можно закрывать.